# Redeclare JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, function, scope

In the following code:

```
var greeting = "hi";

function changeGreeting() {
    if (greeting == "hi") {
        var greeting = "hello";
    }

    alert(greeting);
}

changeGreeting();​
```

...`greeting` is undefined. However if I remove the `var` and change `changeGreeting()` to this:

```
function changeGreeting() {
    if (greeting == "hi") {
        greeting = "hello";
    }

    alert(greeting);
}
```

...I get "hello" as expected.

I would never redeclare a variable like this in my code, but why does this happen?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JavaScript variables have function scope. Thus, the very presence of `var greeting` inside the function will declare a local `greeting` variable, which will be undefined at the time of its mention in `if` condition: the global variable will not be visible inside the function, being overshadowed by the local one. Therefore, the `if` does not happen, the assignment to `hello` doesn't happen, the variable is still undefined.

In the second example, you're using the global variable throughout, it is not overshadowed by a local variable (because, no `var greeting` inside the function), and things work as you expect.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I assumed `var greeting` was an error, and was supposed to be `var currentSize` global variable declaration (which would have been overshadowed in the first example, and used in the second). Otherwise it would be utterly irrelevant to the example.

Comment: @Amadan - It was an error I apologize. This was copied from another SO answer and pared down and I missed the variable naming inconsistency. Thanks again for the answer -- I knew this question would get someone big points ;).

Comment: @levib: No worries, happens. :)

Comment: @Amadan Sorry, I realized that soon after, and deleted my comment.

Comment: So the variable is used before being declared because of a kind of preprocessor !!! Thanks for the answer

Comment: This is the hoist, javascript default behavior. There's the reference, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple: JS hoist the *Variable declarations* to the top of the current scope, but any operations (including assignments) aren't hoisted (within the same scope, see second case explanation), of course. So your snippet is translated to

```
(function()
{
    var currentSize;//undefined
    if (currentSize == 'hi')//always false
    {
        currentSize = 'hello';//assignment that will never be
    }
    alert(currentSize);//alerts undefined, of course
}());
```

By leaving out the var, proceeds to scope scanning (checking for the variable being declared in the global scope). <strike>Sadly, in doing so, the context of the first use of the var is lost (inside a branch), and the assignment is hoisted, too. An implied global is translated to</strike>:
Thank god this isn't true. I assumed it was, because I tested a couple of things in the console that seemed to corroborate this. In this case @amadan is right: you're using the global variable (called `greeting` in your snippet by mistake when I posted this). I'm going to leave the code below (corrected it) to show what implied globals actually are, hoping it helps somebody sometime in understanding scopes/scope-scanning in JS.

```
var currentSize = 'hello';
//well, actually implied globals can be deleted, so it's more like
Object.defineProperty(this,'currentSize',{value:undefined,
                                          writable:true,
                                          enumerable:true,
                                          configurable:true});
(function()
{
    if (currentSize == 'hi')//always false
    {//this still doesn't get executed
        currentSize = 'hello';//assignment that will never be
    }
    alert(currentSize);//alerts undefined
}());
```

Comment: A Nicely Explained Answer On Variable Scope I Learnt a Lot From It To Correct My Concept About Variable Scope in JS

Answer (score -1):

In your first code snippet, you're checking global variable, which doesn't exist -> doesn't pass if condition.

Check out this on javascript scopes and how to work with variables [Javascript garden - function scopes](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes)

Comment: First snippet is _not_ checking a global variable, the function body contains a `var` declaration of that very variable, which is hoisted to the top. It's checking a local `var currentLength;`<-- undefined variable that is GC'ed after the function returns