# Will I have any problems if I declare the same variable multiple times?

Tags: javascript, variables

So lets say I have some code:

```
//Javascript
var elements = [];
function addNumbah1(){
    var i = 1;
    elements.push(i);
}
function addNumbah2(){
    var i = 2;
    elements.push(i);
}
```

And that goes on up to addNumbah999(), is it bad form to declare the `i` variable every time? Will that break anything? Should I do:

```
//Javascript
var elements = [];
var i
function addNumbah1(){
    i = 1;
    elements.push(i);
}
function addNumbah2(){
    i = 2;
    elements.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Your two syntaxes are not equivalent. Do you need *one* or *three* variables?

Comment: declaring variables in a function makes them local to that function - in your second example, you're declaring the variable at global scope

Comment: Your first one declares a local `i` in each function. Every time you call `addNumbah1()`, `i` will be `1`.  The second one declares `i` globally and uses the global in each function, despite being reset to a new value on each call.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @kinakuta is it bad form to change the value of a global over and over again like that? Or is it ok?

Comment: Rather the latter example breaks something. And you should not need to declare 999 very similiar functions, there's something wrong with your code structure.

Comment: @ChapmIndustries: It always depends on your usecase. One time you *want* to change a variable at a higher scope so others will notice it, other times you *mustn't* without breaking something. Tell us what your code is supposed to do (what problem it targets), and we can tell you whether the var should be global or local.

Comment: In general, it's better to avoid declaring variables in global scope. First, it's easy to create collisions, especially if you're using 3rd party scripts as well. Second, variables in global scope won't get garbage collected as long as the page is not refreshed. You don't want to keep variables around in memory longer than you need to. Changing the value of a variable doesn't have anything inherently wrong with it, it's really the two aforementioned things you need to be more concerned with.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer: *NO*, JS hoists all variable declarations to the top of the scope, regardless of how many times you've declared them:

```
var i = 0
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var j = i%2;//declared 10 times, on each iteration
}
```

Will be translated to

```
var i, j; //i is undefined at this point in the code.
for (i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
    j = i%2;//declared 10 times, on each iteration
}
```

In your first example, you're declaring `i` as a variable in a function's scope, which is what you *must* do to avoid cluttering the global scope. The memory these variables use is allocated when the function is called, and deallocated when the function returns (roughly, *closures* form an exception, but that would take us to far). Consider this:

```
var i = 10;
function someF()
{
    var i = 1;
    alert(i);
}
someF();//alerts 1 <-- value of i, local to someF
alert(i);//10, global i is unchanged
```

But if you were to omit the `var`:

```
function someF()
{
    i = 1;
    alert(i);
}
```

You'll  see that 1 is alerted twice. If JS can't find a variable declaration in the current scope, it will look in the higher scopes until a var is found. If no variable is found, JS will create one for you in the highest scope (global). [Check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626094/redeclare-javascript-variable/13626288#13626288) on how implied globals work for a more detailed example, or [read the MDN pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), especially the section on **Name conflicts**

Lastly, I'd like to add that globals, especially implied globals, are *evil*. Also know that the ECMA6 standard is clearly moving away from global variables and introduces support for true block-scopes. [As you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568325/let-var-or-var-to-let)
Oh, and if you want to check if a function uses implied globals: `'use strict';` is a great thing:

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';
    var localVar = 123;//ok
    impliedGlobal = 123;//TypeError!
}());
```

As you can see, implied globals are not allowed. See [MDN on strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) for the full explanation

Comment: Great and Fully Described Answer. It sure deserve a Vote from me

Comment: Thanks! First person to fully and completely give the answer as well as why.

Answer (score 0):

The second form, with global `i` might actually be a bit slower because it's defined in a higher scope, and variables defined in a higher scope take longer to resolve.

Aside from any performance considerations just stick with common guidelines unless performance is really an issue. In this case: **scope your variables as narrowly as possible**.

I would strongly advise you to use the first form.

Answer (score 0):

The first way you did it is fine. Each instance of i would have no knowledge of the other i in the other functions.

You should read this tutorial on [global versus local variables](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3)

Also, could I suggest an optimization. Why can't you just do the following to cover any number (instead of separate functions for each number)?

```
var elements = [];
function addNumbah(number){
    elements.push(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable multiple times..In your code you are declaring Variable i in different scopes here:

```
   //Here you are declaring variable i local to addNumbah1,2 functions 
   var elements = [];
   function addNumbah1(){
       var i = 1; 
       elements.push(i);
   }
   function addNumbah2(){
       var i = 2; 
       elements.push(i);
   } 


   //Here v /variable i has been declared globally
   var elements = [];
   var i
   function addNumbah1(){
       i = 1;   
       elements.push(i);
   }
   function addNumbah2(){
       i = 2;  
       elements.push(i);
   }
```

Note that although you can declare a variable multiple times but *generally its not a good programming practice* as it may cause bugs/problems in your application

Comment: You're not redeclaring any variables here, you're using implied globals! Don't

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Friend I am not declaring it myself. I am just trying to help the person who posted this question by pasting his code and describing the global and local scope in comments

Comment: When I commented, the first snippet wasn't there yet - just the example with a global, and the explanation of variables being reset every time (which is not true at all: only the declaration is hoisted. Expressions can't be hoisted, that's why IIFE's need the `!`, `~` or `()` bits: to turn the function into an expression)

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but I've just been looking into this stuff today, [because of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626094/redeclare-javascript-variable/13626288#13626288). Anyways: happy coding. And again, sorry to be so pedantic about this

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am calling you a friend :-) so don't be sorry. I know you know better than me. You just helped me to improve :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to declare variables with same name in different functions.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside a function only exist in the scope of that function, so having the same variable name across different functions will not break anything.

In fact, it is good form to keep variables in as small of a scope as possible! Global variables can be difficult to manage and can create really bad bugs, especially if one function isn't done using the variable when another function tries to access it.

Specifically for simple variables, declaring

```
var i = 0;
```

every time is perfectly fine.