# Event listener code won't execute function as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a small javascript function which takes data from OpenSignal and then displays it in an html table.

This worked fine up until the point where I tried to make it user friendly by adding in an html form to accept the postcodes input.  I tried to avoid using PHP to do this as my client won't have this installed.

I am adding an event listener to the submit button to detect when the form data has been submitted.  I am then taking this and validating the string contains valid postcode(s).  If they're invalid the program spits out an alert which says "Sorry but you seem to have entered an incorrect postcode.".

If not then I am taking the postcodes and passing them into my function processPostcodesOnServer().  The thing is that this doesn't work inside the event listener.  When I pass postcodes in manually using javascript arrays and call the function outside of the event listener everything works fine.  When I put it in the event listener it simply doesn't work.  I have checked all the inputs to the function are correct and have stepped through the whole program numerous times and cannot find out what is causing the problem.  It seems to me this is just another case of Javascripts random behaviour.

Can anyone help?? This is my HTML and Javascript files (I am using some JQuery so you will have to link with the latest version if you want to run this).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mobile Signals</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="NetworkStats.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="postcodeForm">
Enter postcodes separated by commas<br>
<input type="text" id="postcodes" name="postcodes">
</br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">

</form>

<div id="theDiv">
</div>

<div id ="secondDiv"> </div>

<table id="theTable" border="1">
</table>
```

And Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var input = $('#postcodeForm').serializeArray();

    var postcodeString = input[0]["value"];

    var output = postcodeString.split(",");

    var postcodeString = "";

    // check each postcode to see if there is any false postcodes
    for (var postcode in output) {

        var newPostcode = checkPostCode(output[postcode]);

        if (newPostcode) {

            postcodeString += " true ";
        } else {

            postcodeString += " false ";
        }

    }

    if (postcodeString.indexOf("false") >= 0) {

        // string contains a false so output an error message
        window.alert("Sorry but you seem to have entered an incorrect postcode.")

    } else {
        // all the postcodes are correct, proceed to perform operations on them

        processPostcodesOnServer(output);


    }

}, false);

function processPostcodesOnServer(output) {


    var apiKey = "c590c63f5b3818271a87a3e89fa215ae";
    var distance = 10;
    var tableNumber = 0;
    //var output = ["WR141NE"];

    for (var postcode in output) {

        strippedPostcode = output[postcode].replace(/ /g,'');

        getLatAndLong(strippedPostcode);


    }

    function googleCallback(latitude, longitude, postcode) {

        contactServer(latitude, longitude, postcode);

    }

    /* Function to contact google and convert the postcode to lat long */ 
    function getLatAndLong(postcode) {

        var latitude;
        var longitude;

        var googleXmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var googleUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+ postcode + "&sensor=false";

        googleXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (googleXmlHttp.readyState == 4 && googleXmlHttp.status == 200) {

                var latLong = JSON.parse(googleXmlHttp.responseText);

                latitude = latLong.results[0].geometry.location.lat;

                longitude = latLong.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                googleCallback(latitude, longitude, postcode);
            }
        }
        googleXmlHttp.open("GET", googleUrl, true);
        googleXmlHttp.send();
    }

    function contactServer(latitude, longitude, postcode) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var networkStatsUrl = "http://api.opensignal.com/v2/networkstats.json?lat="+latitude+"&lng="+longitude+"&distance=" + distance + "&apikey=" + apiKey;

        /* 
            Functions to contact server and read JSON response back for NetworkStats
        */

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);


                sortTableData(myArr, postcode);

                //displayData(myArr);

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", networkStatsUrl, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        var functionCount = -1;

        function sortTableData(arr, postcode) {

            tableNumber++;

            $("body").append("</br>" + postcode + "</br>");

            theTable = "<table id='table"+ tableNumber + "' border='1'> </table>"

            $("body").append(theTable);

            var column1 = new Array();
            var column2 = new Array();
            var column3 = new Array();
            var column4 = new Array();
            var column5 = new Array();
            var column6 = new Array();
            var column7 = new Array();

            //var output = '<table border="1">';
            //var output = "";

            for (var obj in arr) {  

                // find all the networks 
                if ((typeof arr[obj] === 'object') && (obj == "networkRank")) {

                    var networks = new Object();
                    networks = arr[obj]; 

                    var allNetworkKeys = Object.keys(networks);

                    //console.log(allNetworkKeys);

                    var networksArray = new Array();

                    $.each(networks, function(networkKey, networkValue){
                        //Do something with your key and value.

                        column1.push(networkKey);

                        if (networkKey.substring(0, 7) == "network") {

                            $.each(networkValue, function(networkTypeKey, networkTypeValue){

                                if (networkTypeKey == "type2G") {

                                    column2.push('');
                                    column3.push(networkTypeKey);

                                    for (var variable in networkTypeValue) {

                                        column2.push(variable);
                                        column3.push(networkTypeValue[variable]);
                                    }

                                } else if (networkTypeKey == "type3G") {

                                    column4.push('');
                                    column5.push(networkTypeKey);

                                    for (var variable in networkTypeValue) {

                                        column4.push(variable);
                                        column5.push(networkTypeValue[variable]);
                                    }

                                } else if (networkTypeKey == "type4G") {

                                    column6.push('');
                                    column7.push(networkTypeKey);

                                    for (var variable in networkTypeValue) {

                                        column6.push(variable);
                                        column7.push(networkTypeValue[variable]);
                                    }
                                }


                            });

                            //console.log(column1); 
                        }

                        //console.log(column1, column2, column3, column4);
                        displayTable(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
                        column1 = []; column2 = []; column3 = []; column4 = []; column5 = []; column6 = []; column7 = [];
                    });

                }

            }


        }

        var counter = 0;

        function displayTable(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7) {

            var output = ""

            //console.log(counter);
            counter++;

            var column1Length = column1.length;
            var column2Length = column2.length;
            var column3Length = column3.length;
            var column4Length = column4.length;
            var column5Length = column5.length;
            var column6Length = column6.length;
            var column7Length = column7.length;

            var highestNumber = Math.max(column1Length, column2Length, column3Length, column4Length, column5Length, column6Length, column7Length);

            for (var i=0; i<highestNumber; i++) {

                var column1Reference = column1[i];
                var column2Reference = column2[i];
                var column3Reference = column3[i];
                var column4Reference = column4[i];
                var column5Reference = column5[i];
                var column6Reference = column6[i];
                var column7Reference = column7[i];

                if (column1Reference === void 0) { 
                    column1Reference = " " 
                }
                if (column2Reference === void 0) { 
                    column2Reference = " " 
                }
                if (column3Reference === void 0) { 
                    column3Reference = " " 
                }
                if (column4Reference === void 0) { 
                    column4Reference = " " 
                }
                if (column5Reference === void 0) { 
                    column5Reference = " " 
                }
                if (column6Reference === void 0) { 
                    column6Reference = " " 
                }
                if (column7Reference === void 0) { 
                    column7Reference = " " 
                }


                output += "<tr>";

                output += "<td>" + column1Reference + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + column2Reference + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + column3Reference + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + column4Reference + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + column5Reference + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + column6Reference + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + column7Reference + "</td>";
                output += "</tr>";

            }
            //output += "</table>";

            //var table = document.getElementById('theTable');

            //console.log(output);

            //oldOutput = table.innerHTML;

            //table.innerHTML = oldOutput + output;

            $("#table" +tableNumber).append(output);

            console.log(output);



        }


    }

}

});
```

Comment: Could you strip out some of the unrelated code please?

Comment: Also do you want to use jquery or not? Because you have a mix of vanilla js and jq and its not at all clear why.

Comment: Hi I've stripped the code down a little bit but theres not a whole lot I can take out without removing stuff which is essential for understanding the problem.

Comment: I tried to use vanilla JS but I found there were some things I was getting stuck on so I had to import JQuery to overcome them.

Comment: Try using this `$('#submitButton').on(` instead of `document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener(`.

Comment: You shouldn't listed to click event on submit button anyway. You should listen to `submit` event on the form. Use this: `$('#postcodeForm').on('submit', function()...`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it simply doesn't work"? Nothing happens? Or you always get an error?

Comment: I've tried both of the above two suggestions.  Thanks very much, but neither made a difference.

Comment: @Siguza It doesn't print the desired output.  I've stepped through it but something seems to be going awry with the sortTableData function. The script seems to just stop , just short of completing the task.  It doesn't get into the displayTable function at all.  It must be something to do with the fact that it has been placed in the click listener code because if you call processPostcodesOnServer with a valid postcode array outside of this it will output successfully.

Comment: I'm trying to do $('#postcodeForm').on('submit', function() but its simply not detecting the click event.   I've tried with click as the first argument as well but its not attaching to the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got it working.
The table would actually be displayed, if only submitting the form wouldn't reload the page.

There are two ways around this:

1. #### Change your `click` handler to a `submit` handler *and cancel the event*!

   Replace

   ```
   document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
       // ...
   }, false);
   ```

   by

   ```
   document.getElementById('postcodeForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       // ...
   }, false);
   ```
2. #### Remove the form:

   That would be as simple as removing `<form id="postcodeForm">` and `</form>` from your HTML code, but since you use `$('#postcodeForm')` in JS, you're gonna have to change

   ```
   var input = $('#postcodeForm').serializeArray();
   var postcodeString = input[0]["value"];
   var output = postcodeString.split(",");
   ```

   into

   ```
   var output = document.getElementById('postcodes').value.split(",");
   ```

   to make it work.
   (Inlining `postcodeString` is not actually necessary, but I suggest it, see below.)
   If you go with this option, I suggest also removing the `name` attribute from `#postcodes`, simply because it serves no purpose.

But regardless of which option you choose, you should fix all those `</br>`s: It's `<br>` in HTML 5 (and it was `<br/>` in HTML 4, but never `</br>`).
(And don't forget those in your JS!)

And what is the `googleCallback` function good for, if it only passes its arguments to a function with the exact same list of parameters? Why not use `contactServer` directly?

And this code is really inefficient:

```
var postcodeString = "";
// check each postcode to see if there is any false postcodes
for(var postcode in output)
{
    var newPostcode = checkPostCode(output[postcode]);
    if(newPostcode)
    {
        postcodeString += " true ";
    }
    else
    {
        postcodeString += " false ";
    }
}
if(postcodeString.indexOf("false") >= 0)
{
    // string contains a false so output an error message
    window.alert("Sorry but you seem to have entered an incorrect postcode.")
}
else
{
    // all the postcodes are correct, proceed to perform operations on them
    processPostcodesOnServer(output);
}
```

I mean, strings, really? Consider:

```
// check each postcode to see if there is any invalid postcodes
for(var postcode in output)
{
    if(checkPostCode(output[postcode]) === false)
    {
        // current postcode is invalid so output an error message and return
        window.alert("Sorry but you seem to have entered an incorrect postcode.");
        return;
    }
// at this point, all the postcodes are valid, proceed to perform operations on them
processPostcodesOnServer(output);
```

Also, you use a lot of variables only exactly once, resulting in quite an overhead.
For example, this:

```
var column1Length = column1.length;
var column2Length = column2.length;
var column3Length = column3.length;
var column4Length = column4.length;
var column5Length = column5.length;
var column6Length = column6.length;
var column7Length = column7.length;
var highestNumber = Math.max(column1Length, column2Length, column3Length, column4Length, column5Length, column6Length, column7Length);
```

Which could be shortened to this:

```
var highestNumber = Math.max(column1.length, column2.length, column3.length, column4.length, column5.length, column6.length, column7.length);
```

Sure this makes the line a little longer, but for 7 additional characters you can save 7 entire lines!

Or, your `displayTable` function could really be shortened to this:

```
function displayTable()
{
    var output = '';
    var highestNumber = Math.max(arguments[0].length, arguments[1].length, arguments[2].length, arguments[3].length, arguments[4].length, arguments[5].length, arguments[6].length);
    for(var i = 0; i < highestNumber; i++)
    {
        output += '<tr>';
        for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            output += '<td>' + arguments[j][i] + '</td>';
        }
        output += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#table' + tableNumber).append(output);
}
```

Then, you have a lot of `{1}` in your RegEx - why? `[0-9]{1}` is equal to `[0-9]` (or `\d`, but with that be careful to escape `\` if using it in strings).

And finally, I suggest you run your code through [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or something similar to get rid of inconsistencies (be careful with JS**L**int though, that one has really aggressive and unreasonable conventions).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yeah that was the problem alright.  And thanks for your useful tips.  I'll see what I can do about them.

Answer (score 0):

You have `var postcodeString` twice.

`var` keyword should only be used once per scope.

Comment: While declaring a variable multiple times is certainly not pretty, it is not actually wrong, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13630373/2302862).