# New to JS, trying to understand hoisting

Tags: javascript, undefined, hoisting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redeclare JavaScript Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626094/redeclare-javascript-variable)

I have the next piece of code:

```
var i = 11;
alert(i);
function a(){
    alert(i);
    var i = 2;
    alert(i);
}
a()
```

The second `alert(i)` (inside the function) produces `undefined`. I'm guessing it has to do with the way JS engine runs through the code - maybe it doesn't store variables first, before going throught the lines?

Anyway I thought that this is not a problem is JS because it supports hoisting. I probably got it wrong - does anybody care to explain?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of duplicate questions on this subject: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630373/will-i-have-any-problems-if-i-declare-the-same-variable-multiple-times/13630592#13630592), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626094/redeclare-javascript-variable/13626288#13626288) deal with the matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does indeed hoist *declarations* to the top of the scope in which they occur, but assignments happen at the place you would expect them to. Your code is effectively parsed like this:

```
/* Function declarations are hoisted first, which is why you can invoke a
   function before it appears to be defined in the source */
function a() {
    var i; // Declaration is hoisted (this i shadows the outer i)
    alert(i);
    i = 2; // Assignment to local i happens in place
    alert(i);
}
var i; // Declaration is hoisted (at this point, i === undefined)
i = 11; // Assignment happens in place
alert(i);
a();
```

This is detailed [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5). Upon entering a new execution context, the following happens:

> For each *VariableDeclaration* and *VariableDeclarationNoIn d* in *code*, in source text order do
>
> - Let *dn* be the *Identifier* in *d*.
> - Let *varAlreadyDeclared* be the result of calling *env’s* HasBinding concrete method passing *dn* as the argument.
> - If *varAlreadyDeclared* is `false`, then
>
>   - Call *env’s* CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn* and *configurableBindings* as the arguments.
>   - Call *env’s* SetMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn*, `undefined`, and *strict* as the arguments.

Comment: Doesn't hoisting occur when the interpreter comes across a function variable that does not have the keyword `var` before? OP is creating a new variable `i` that is function-scoped, right?

Comment: @limelights - Hoisting occurs upon entering any execution context. When control enters the `a` function, the interpreter looks for any declarations and creates bindings in the environment record of the new execution context for their identifiers before starting to execute the code.

Comment: Indeed the `var i;` on the first line of `function a()` has a local scope to the function therefore will be `undefined` until `i = 2;`

Comment: @JamesAllardice ah, I see. So is it wrong to say that when control hoists a variable it doesn't always hoist to the global context but to the top of the local context unless the keyword `var` is left out?

Comment: @limelights - If the `var` keyword is left out then you don't have a declaration. It won't get hoisted at all. You would simply be assigning to a property of the global object.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: unless, of course, scope scanning manages to resolve to a variable declared in a higher scope, but that's another matter :)

Comment: @JamesAllardice Thanks, I get how it works now. :) If I could give two upvotes I would. ;)